# Is there any tool to execute iOS automation scripts in Windows using python?

Tags: ios, xcode, appium-ios, python-appium

I'm looking to setup iOS test automation **in Windows**. The scripts are written in Python using Selenium and UIAutomator libraries. I have to run the test on an iphone, which i have available with me. But they should be executed from Windows platform.

Here's what i already know. Appium and `XCode` work together in MAC OS to execute these scripts on iOS. But Appium in Windows doesn't have the driver to interface with `iOS`. I've looked into Appium Studio for Windows, but i'm still looking for better alternatives.

There are following softwares that provide an SDK to execute scripts on iOS, but do not work with Python:

TestProject’s SDK has a Java and C# (.NET Core) implementation.

**NativeScript sidekick :** User can choose to use Angular, JavaScript or TypeScript.

Comment: If you have a VM that runs on OS X , it may be possible.

The main challenge is that you need to access to iPhone - that will need xcode which is not supported in Windows.

Comment: appium, if you really need to run automation scripts I recommend pythonista for iOS , the times that I used it I’ve had no issues besides not being able to install some modules , like pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

There are various vendors which provide software that allows you to test iOS devices with Appium on Windows. Examples include [Quamotion xcuitrunner](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/xcuitrunner/getting-started/) or [Experitest Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/).

If you're on Linux, you can also try the [appium-docker-ios](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/quamotion/appium-docker-ios/) Docker image.