# Can iOS device automation be performed on a Windows machine using the Robot Framework?

Tags: python, ios, windows, appium, robotframework

I have a requirement to Automate scripts on iOS devices using the Robot framework/Python on the Windows platform.

What are all things I required in order to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set up everything you need on Windows for iOS device. Instead you need to use macOS.

Maybe the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541995/is-there-any-tool-to-execute-ios-automation-scripts-in-windows-using-python) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't automate any iOS scripts from windows system . The main requirement for iOSDriver to communicate with appium scripts and to your iOS device requires xcode app . Which is not there onto windows .

Answer (score 0):

Appium can automate iOS device tests via WebDriverAgent.

WebDriverAgent can be run through multiple open source multi-platform tools from Windows:

1. go-ios
2. tidevice
3. others...

You will need Xcode to first build WDA though before you can deploy it to a device. Once it is installed on the device ( until the signing expires at least ) you can run WDA from any OS ( Mac, Windows, Linux ) using the various tools.